# Is there a way to fill in a matrix with extrapolated data?

Tags: r, matrix

Basically, I calculated the mean of each row of a matrix

```
> mat <- matrix(c(45,34,1,3,4325,23,1,2,5,7,3,4,32,734,2),ncol=3)
> mat
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]   45   23    3
[2,]   34    1    4
[3,]    1    2   32
[4,]    3    5  734
[5,] 4325    7    2

> mat2 <-t(rowMeans(mat))
> mat2
         [,1] [,2]     [,3]     [,4]     [,5]
[1,] 23.66667   13 11.66667 247.3333 1444.667
> dim(mat2)
[1] 1 5
```

What I'd like to do is fill an empty matrix with the calculated values so that it looks like 'mat3'

```
> mat2 <- matrix(numeric(0), 5,5)
> mat2
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
[1,]   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA
[2,]   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA
[3,]   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA
[4,]   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA
[5,]   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA


> mat3
           [,1]     [,2]         [,5] 
[1,]   23.66667 23.66667  ....   23.66667 
[2,]   13.00000 13.00000  ....   13.00000 
[3,]   11.66667 11.66667  ....   11.66667
[4,]   247.3333 247.3333  ....   247.3333
[5,]   1444.667 1444.667  ....   1444.667
```

Is there any way to do this without filling each cell manually?

Comment: Joran's answer is fine.  I just wanted to point out that this is not an extrapolation.  What you're asking for is purely a repetition of some calculations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, via R's recycling functionality:

```
mat <- matrix(c(45,34,1,3,4325,23,1,2,5,7,3,4,32,734,2),ncol=3)
mat2 <- rowMeans(mat)
mat2
[1]   23.66667   13.00000   11.66667  247.33333 1444.66667
> matrix(mat2,5,5)

           [,1]       [,2]       [,3]       [,4]       [,5]
[1,]   23.66667   23.66667   23.66667   23.66667   23.66667
[2,]   13.00000   13.00000   13.00000   13.00000   13.00000
[3,]   11.66667   11.66667   11.66667   11.66667   11.66667
[4,]  247.33333  247.33333  247.33333  247.33333  247.33333
[5,] 1444.66667 1444.66667 1444.66667 1444.66667 1444.66667
```

When you give `matrix` a vector of length 5, and tell it the resulting matrix should be 5x5, it extends your vector to fill the rest of the matrix automatically.

Comment: Well that's simple enough. Thank you.